# How to convert lapply output to a single matrix in R

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list of data frames, organized by year. I am using `lapply` to get the summary for a single variable in each data frame. The output follows the list and gives a summary for each year, one by one. However, I want the output in the form of a single table with years for rows. How do I do this? An example using the iris dataset shows my problem:

```
x <- split(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species)
lapply(x, summary)
```

And the output is:

```
$setosa
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   4.300   4.800   5.000   5.006   5.200   5.800
```

Similarly for the other two.

I want the output organized as a single table like with:

```
> sapply(x, summary)
        setosa versicolor virginica
Min.     4.300      4.900     4.900
1st Qu.  4.800      5.600     6.225
Median   5.000      5.900     6.500
Mean     5.006      5.936     6.588
3rd Qu.  5.200      6.300     6.900
Max.     5.800      7.000     7.900
```

But with setosa, versicolor, virginica (or years in my case) on the left and Min... Max up top. I can flip the axes around in ggplot, but reading the table as-is is more intuitive with the years on the left. I came across a number of discussions about converting `lapply` output but the ones I came across were all measuring a single stat like mean or median. Thanks.

Comment: Just `t`ranspose the output of `sapply`.

Comment: Thanks @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 that worked with the iris example but not with my data. Another user suggested `with(iris, do.call(rbind, by(Sepal.Length, Species, summary)))` which worked with iris and my data but by the time I tried it and composed my reply saying it worked and a second suggestion did not - the post disappeared!  I will retrace my steps and see why `t`ranspose is not working with my data

Comment: I've voted to undelete the answer. Will see if @RichScriven does so voluntarily....

Comment: I undeleted my answer.  Sorry, I figured `t()` would do the trick.

Comment: The title of your Q asks for returning a single matrix but later you talk about plotting with `ggplot2` which requires a data.frame as input.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 - I couldn't get `t()`to work with my data. I suspect because I don't (yet) grasp aspects of how the list is structured. `> str(test)
List of 13
 $ 2004:Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':`  Versus the `str()` of the iris list which simply says "List of 3" with no mention of classes. The end result is `sapply()` on the simple list produces a matrix that can be `t`ransposed but not with a list of data.tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good time to use `by()`.  It eliminates the need for the call to `split()`, is all done in one line, and returns a matrix.

```
with(iris, do.call(rbind, by(Sepal.Length, Species, summary)))
#            Min. 1st Qu. Median  Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
# setosa      4.3   4.800    5.0 5.006     5.2  5.8
# versicolor  4.9   5.600    5.9 5.936     6.3  7.0
# virginica   4.9   6.225    6.5 6.588     6.9  7.9
```

If you still wish to use manual split-apply-combine method, then it would be

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(x, summary))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large data.frame, I recommend *not to split* it into pieces but to use `data.table` for grouping by year. With the `iris` data set this could be done along

```
library(data.table)
setDT(copy(iris))[, as.list(summary(Sepal.Length)), by = Species]
#      Species Min. 1st Qu. Median  Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
#1:     setosa  4.3   4.800    5.0 5.006     5.2  5.8
#2: versicolor  4.9   5.600    5.9 5.936     6.3  7.0
#3:  virginica  4.9   6.225    6.5 6.588     6.9  7.9
```

`as.list()` ensures the output of `summary()` appears column-wise as requested.

The result is a `data.table` (not a `matrix`) which can be used directly in a subsequent `ggplot()` call.

Note that `copy(iris)` is only required here because the `iris` data set is locked to prevent modifying its variable bindings. With your own data.frame `df` you would simply use `setDT(df)` to coerce to data.table without copying.

### Add-on

The OP mentioned that he uses the result for plotting with `ggplot2`. Now, `ggplot2` works best when data are provided in *long format*. Reshaping a data.table from wide to long format can be conveniently done with `melt()`

```
wideDT <- setDT(copy(iris))[, summary(Sepal.Length), by = Species]
longDT <- melt(wideDT, id.vars = "Species")
longDT
#       Species variable value
# 1:     setosa     Min. 4.300
# 2: versicolor     Min. 4.900
# 3:  virginica     Min. 4.900
# 4:     setosa  1st Qu. 4.800
# 5: versicolor  1st Qu. 5.600
# 6:  virginica  1st Qu. 6.225
# 7:     setosa   Median 5.000
# 8: versicolor   Median 5.900
# 9:  virginica   Median 6.500
#10:     setosa     Mean 5.006
#11: versicolor     Mean 5.936
#12:  virginica     Mean 6.588
#13:     setosa  3rd Qu. 5.200
#14: versicolor  3rd Qu. 6.300
#15:  virginica  3rd Qu. 6.900
#16:     setosa     Max. 5.800
#17: versicolor     Max. 7.000
#18:  virginica     Max. 7.900
```

Comment: Thank you this worked (too). It helped that my data was in a data.table to begin with, and I was grouping variables by year; but didn't think of `as.list(summary())` - simple and elegant. I should also probably invest time in understanding the differences between a df and a dt and not use them interchangeably. That said, even though your answer is what I am going to use, I am marking @Rich's answer as accepted because it produced results  in the specified "matrix". If there are SO protocols covering in-artfully phrased questions with multiple correct answers, glad to revise / revisit if so.